# What is the difference between qpid-proton-c vs qpid-cpp

Tags: qpid

I am confused about the difference between qpid-proton-c and qpid-cpp. Can someone enlighten me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both proton and qpid-cpp are projects under the Apache Qpid umbrella, but they are meant for different things. qpid-cpp is a full blown JMS/AMQP broker implementation. A java version of this exists, but the cpp version ostensibly performs better.

The proton library on the other hand is a lightweight messaging library with several language bindings. You can use proton in one of the available languages to connect to and interact with any AMQP broker, including qpid-cpp or qpid-java. Proton also provides example implementations to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the featuresets of several AMQP implementations are different from language to language. Proton implements the exactly same featureset and interfaces for Java, C and JavaScript. This is guaranteed by sourcecode generation.

Imho looking at this in a really abstract way, you could indicate proton as a language crossing Messaging API like the JMS is for Java.